# How to better manage beans?

Tags: java, design, architecture, web-development, crud

In my application - I have to expose services using JAX-RS(for mobile platform) and consume the same set of services in a JSF based web app.

Now, I have `@Entity` beans for persistence layer, `@ManagedBean` beans from presentation layer and another set of beans for mapping `JAX-RS` related `request objects`.

Lets take login operation for example -

**Case 1** - Consuming services from mobile devices - a rest request comes in, then my application receive the request data in rest service related `LoginRS` object and then pass it to the persistence facade which in turn first maps `LoginRS` attributes to `Login` entity and then does the necessary validation.

**Case 2** Consuming from web app - similarly as above the `managed` bean attributes to rest related `LoginRS` and then as stated in `case 1` to login entity before the necessary validation kicks in. Here, I can think of another approach which is to pass the managed bean straight to the persistence facade for conversion and validation but then it defeats the purpose of consuming web service.

`Question` - Is there a better way to deal with the above scenario? Or, is it possible to avoid three types of beans?

I'm not using `Spring`/`EJB` but open to both of them if required.

Also, please feel free to edit the tags as you see fit.

Comment: To better manage beans, hire a bean counter.

Comment: :). Can't afford. Any other thought?